# Prove that this infinite product converges uniformly,

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, analyticity, infinite-product

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of complex numbers such that

(i) $0<|a_n|<1$,

(ii) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1-|a_n|)<\infty$

Prove that the infinite product

$$\prod_1^\infty \frac{(a_n -z)|a_n|}{(1-\bar {a_n}z)a_n}$$

converges uniformly for $|z| \le r$ for any r <1, hence defining a holomorphic function in the unit disc.

I want to use the very useful theorem that $\prod_1^\infty (1+b_n)<\infty$ if and only if $\sum_1^\infty |b_n| < \infty$, but I am having some trouble with getting the factor in the form of $(1+b_n)$.

Also, assumption (ii) seems, at least on the surface, not useful / redundant, and that the primary goal is to get the $(1+a_n)$ form, so that we can immediately look at the sum of |an|.

Any hints on the problem -- or comments on how assumption (ii) is useful -- are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: (ii) implies that $|a_n|\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Ah, very cool @Math1000.  So, the goal is still to get the $(1+a_n)$ form, but noting that $|a_n| -> 1$.  Thanks so much :-)

Comment: You keep using the notation $a_n$ for two different things - the sequence of complex numbers that's given, and that other sequence, where you say the product of $a_n$ converges if and only if etc. Bad idea. Anyway, if $A$ is anything whatever, you can get $A$ into the form $1$ plus something like so: $A = 1 + (A-1)$. So if we say $b_n=(a_n-z)|a_n|/(1-\overline a_nz)a_n$ you need to show $\sum|1-b_n|$ converges.

Comment: And now when you write out $1-b_n|$ and simplify you may begin to see what $\sum(1-|a_n|)$ has to do with it...

Comment: Hi @DavidC.Ullrich, thanks so much for your helpful comments.  I have now changed the labeling of the sequence in the Theorem to be different from the sequence in the problem statement.  I had *just* set up an algebraic equation to solve 1+x = (infinite product factor), but I see now that your method is better to go with.  I will try both methods now.  Thanks so much, Professor Ullrich.

Comment: I thought you were that guy... No charge. That one a month or so ago was fun - student actually listening to suggestions, working on figuring it out with hints. The way it's supposed to work here, but it usually doesn't.